# How to set the default browser in NixOS?

Tags: gnome3, chrome, nixos

I am using NixOS with Gnome, and would like to set Chromium as the default browser.

The 'Details' section of my settings, under 'default applications' shows the following:

[image]

Both Chromium and Firefox have been installed on my system (Chromium via `$ nix-env -i chromium`), and yet they do not show up under the drop-down for 'Web', which shows only the one option.

**How can I set Chromium to be my default browser?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NixOS does not manage user-specific configuration. Full-stop.

As for the browsers not being found by the configuration dialog, try installing them via `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` instead of with `nix-env`.

### Tip

If you install packages declaratively and imperatively you'll end up having to manage two dependency trees. One via `nixos-rebuild --upgrade boot` and another by `nix-channel --update && nix-env -u`. Meaning that if you forget either update process you'll end up with old packages installed.

Answer (score 7):

#### For Apps Following the XDG Spec

As of NixOS 21.11 or later, one may now set `xdg.mime.defaultApplications`. For example, to make Qutebrowser the default web browser:

```
xdg.mime.defaultApplications = {
  "text/html" = "org.qutebrowser.qutebrowser.desktop";
  "x-scheme-handler/http" = "org.qutebrowser.qutebrowser.desktop";
  "x-scheme-handler/https" = "org.qutebrowser.qutebrowser.desktop";
  "x-scheme-handler/about" = "org.qutebrowser.qutebrowser.desktop";
  "x-scheme-handler/unknown" = "org.qutebrowser.qutebrowser.desktop";
}
```

Ensure `xdg.mime.enable` is `true`, which is the default, or the above snippet will have no effect.

##### For Electron apps:

Electron based desktop applications seem to pull their default browser instance for opening links from the `DEFAULT_BROWSER` environmental variable. Which expects to be set to either a binary which can be found in the `PATH`, or a full path to the binary to use.

Another example, again setting qutebrowser:

```
environment.sessionVariables.DEFAULT_BROWSER = "${pkgs.qutebrowser}/bin/qutebrowser"
```

Answer (score 4):

##### For Home Manager:

The system-wide settings on nrdxp's answer may be ignored for one reason or another, so if it doesn't work and you're using Home Manager, try setting them per-user. To do that, you need to replace `mime` with `mimeApps` and set `enable = true`, since it's disabled by default. Adapting their snippet we get:

```
home-manager.users.<YOUR_USER_NAME>.xdg.mimeApps = {
  enable = true;
  
  defaultApplications = {
    "text/html" = "org.qutebrowser.qutebrowser.desktop";
    "x-scheme-handler/http" = "org.qutebrowser.qutebrowser.desktop";
    "x-scheme-handler/https" = "org.qutebrowser.qutebrowser.desktop";
    "x-scheme-handler/about" = "org.qutebrowser.qutebrowser.desktop";
    "x-scheme-handler/unknown" = "org.qutebrowser.qutebrowser.desktop";
  };
};
```

You need to do this with every user you want this configured for.

Answer (score 2):

There is a typo in @nrdxp's answer an s too much in `sessionsVariables`.
It should be:
Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to comment.

```
environment.sessionVariables.DEFAULT_BROWSER = "${pkgs.qutebrowser}/bin/qutebrowser"
```